# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' when inside a function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the below code outside of a function which returns a text value, however the same code in a function returns the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/danielpereira/PycharmProjects/fmoves_scraper/movie_scraper.py", line 14, in <module>
    find_movie(line)
  File "/Users/danielpereira/PycharmProjects/fmoves_scraper/movie_scraper.py", line 9, in find_movie
    resolution = soup.find('span', class_='item mr-3').text
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The contents of the movies.text file are 2 links:

```
https://fmovies.app/movie/watch-top-gun-maverick-online-5448
https://fmovies.app/movie/watch-thor-love-and-thunder-online-66670
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def find_movie(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, 'html.parser')
    resolution = soup.find('span', class_='item mr-3').text
    return resolution


with open('movies.txt', 'r') as file:
    for links in file:
        movie_link = find_movie(links)
        print(movie_link)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error message.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: It would seem that `soup.find('span', class_='item mr-3')` returned `None`.

Comment: See [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. If you need more help, add the contents of `movies.txt` to your question.

Comment: According to error, the `soup` didn't found any element and hence it's `None` and directly on `None` you are accessing `.text` property. I would suggest you to try printing which URL is giving error i.e. not having such element

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to work, I think the problem is in the reading of the urls, try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def find_movie(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, "html.parser")
    resolution = soup.find("span", class_="item mr-3").text
    return resolution


with open("movies.txt", "r") as file:
    for links in file.readlines():
        movie_link = find_movie(links.strip())
        print(movie_link)
```

with output:

```
HD
CAM
```

Comment: I am trying to read in multiple links from the txt file with a context manager, this is where it fails and throws and error, the method you suggested works.